# iphone NSCondition - App is crashing when "wait" is called

Tags: iphone

I am working on iphone app.
I created a custom class that derives from "NSCondition".
The following piece of code is working fine with iPhone SDK 3.1.3

```
- (bool)waitForFinish {
@try {
    [self lock];
    while (!done) {
        [self wait];
    }
}
@finally {
    [self unlock];
}
return success;
}
```

The app is crashing on iPhone SDK 4.0 at line "[self wait]"
What might be the reason for crash in iPhone 4.0 SDK?
I noticed that the loop "while(!done)" is running for 4 times and then its crashing.

//Adding more info

```
-(void)releaseUse {
[self lock];
@try {
    done = 1;
    [self broadcast];
}
@finally {
    [self unlock];
}
[self notifyComplete];
```

}

The above function is called when a file is downloaded so that it will send a broadcast message to come out of wait state.

Apple says that in iPhone OS 4, it fixed a bug related to NSCondition. (I don't know what's the bug). I think it might be causing error in iPhone SDK 4 and not in iPhone SDK 3.1

Comment: If you post some details about the crash, and other relevant information, eg. who is calling signal - then it might be easier to help you.

Comment: I'm just getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in the log.

Comment: You might want to add a timed trigger to that while loop or you'll end up calling it A LOT